# Really true that .properties files must be encoded in ISO-8859-1 before java 9?

Tags: java, encoding, properties-file

I often read that .properties file should/must be encoded in ISO-8859-1
before Java 9. I never had problems to load and store .properties in UTF-8.
Or is it recommended for Resource Bundle files only to use 8859-1 ?

```
public static void utf8_test()
{
    Path pfile    = Paths.get("C:\\temp_\\properties_utf8.properties");
    Path pfileOut = Paths.get("C:\\temp_\\properties_utf-8_out.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();

    try ( BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pfile,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
          BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(pfileOut,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        )
    {
        props.load(br);
        props.setProperty("test","test prop;Гадание по телефону;öüµäß@;Euro sign;€");
        props.list(System.out);

        props.store(bw,"comment");

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
} //--- end

The input file is:
foo = aaa
utf_test = Гадание
bar = bbb

The output file is:
#comment
#Wed Dec 25 15:11:28 CET 2019
utf_test=Гадание
bar=bbb
﻿foo=aaa
test=test prop;Гадание по телефону;öüµäß@;Euro sign;€
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Properties File

Here's the class documentation of [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) (Java 13):

> The `load(Reader)` / `store(Writer, String)` methods load and store properties from and to a character based stream in a simple line-oriented format specified below. **The `load(InputStream)` / `store(OutputStream, String)` methods work the same way as the `load(Reader)` / `store(Writer, String)` pair, except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding** [emphasis added]. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of *The Java™ Language Specification*; only a single `'u'` character is allowed in an escape sequence.
>
> The `loadFromXML(InputStream)` and `storeToXML(OutputStream, String, String)` methods load and store properties in a simple XML format. By default the UTF-8 character encoding is used, however a specific encoding may be specified if required. Implementations are required to support UTF-8 and UTF-16 and may support other encodings. An XML properties document has the following DOCTYPE declaration: [...]

And here's the documentation of [`Properties#load(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) (again, Java 13):

> Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input byte stream. The input stream is in a simple line-oriented format as specified in `load(Reader)` and **is assumed to use the ISO 8859-1 character encoding** [emphasis added]; that is each byte is one Latin1 character. Characters not in Latin1, and certain special characters, are represented in keys and elements using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of *The Java™ Language Specification*.
>
> The specified stream remains open after this method returns.

---

### Resource Bundles

While here's the class documentation of [`PropertyResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) (again, Java 13):

> **API Note:**
>
> `PropertyResourceBundle` can be constructed either from an `InputStream` or a `Reader`, which represents a property file. Constructing a `PropertyResourceBundle` instance from an `InputStream` requires that the input stream be encoded in UTF-8. By default, if a `MalformedInputException` or an `UnmappableCharacterException` occurs on reading the input stream, then the `PropertyResourceBundle` instance resets to the state before the exception, re-reads the input stream in ISO-8859-1, and continues reading. If the system property `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.encoding` is set to either "ISO-8859-1" or "UTF-8", the input stream is solely read in that encoding, and throws the exception if it encounters an invalid sequence. If "ISO-8859-1" is specified, characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 encoding must be represented by Unicode Escapes as defined in section 3.3 of *The Java™ Language Specification* whereas the other constructor which takes a `Reader` does not have that limitation. Other encoding values are ignored for this system property. The system property is read and evaluated when initializing this class. Changing or removing the property has no effect after the initialization.

It's this class that has changed. If you look at [the Java 8 documentation of `PropertyResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) you'll see it only accepts ISO 8859-1 encoding when constructed with an `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks a lot,The restriction of ISO-8859-1 -if i understand correctly- is for using the Input/OutStream for load and store. If I use the Reader/Writer i'am free to use any encoding. I'm on Java 8

Comment: That's how I understand it as well, since you specify the encoding with the `Reader` / `Writer`.

Comment: Thanks for answering on Christmas

Comment: The fact that `Properties` has methods accepting `Reader` or `Writer` is the reason why this class didn’t need changes. In contrast, when you use `ResourceBundle.getBundle​(…)` and it constructs a `PropertyResourceBundle` from a resource automatically, you have no API for specifying an encoding.